# UITableView - How to delete file while deleting cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to delete a csv file while deleting a cell, But I'm getting the next error when I pressed delete:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   2]'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Code:

```
//
```

/

```
/  CameraViewController.m
//  oFiOSstoryboard
//
//  Created by Dorald on 24/05/15.
//
//

#import "CameraViewController.h"
#import "resultsDetailView.h"


@interface CameraViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *data;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *timeStamp;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSMutableArray *dirList;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *csvRow;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *dataArray;


- (IBAction)didTapDeleteBtn:(id)sender;


@end

                                 ////////////////////////csv readder
NSMutableArray *tableDataArray;

NSString *bundleRoot = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSDirectoryEnumerator *direnum = [manager enumeratorAtPath:bundleRoot];
NSString *filename;
NSMutableArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *strPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"file" ofType:@"csv"];
NSString *strFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:strPath  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSMutableArray *timeStampb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ;
NSMutableArray *arrayToDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ;
NSMutableArray *filePathsArray ;
//NSMutableArray *dirList= [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ;
NSString *currentcsvfile;
NSString *csvfilenameSave;

@implementation CameraViewController



@synthesize data;


- (void)viewDidLoad  {
[super viewDidLoad];
  // ////lista de documentos

    self.data.scrollEnabled = YES;

    self.data.delegate = self;
    self.data.dataSource = self;


    //filePathsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; ;


    self.data.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = YES;


    self.dataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    NSInteger count = 100;
    for (NSInteger i = count; i>=0; i--) {
        NSString *title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell %ld",i];
        [self.dataArray addObject:title];
    }
    NSMutableArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSFileManager *manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSMutableArray*   fileList = [manager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    //--- Listing file by name sort
    NSLog(@"\n File list %@",fileList);

    //---- Sorting files by extension
    NSMutableArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory error:nil];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF EndsWith '.csv'"];
    filePathsArray =  [filePathsArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    NSLog(@"\n\n Sorted files by extension %@",filePathsArray);



    self.dirList = [filePathsArray mutableCopy];

    NSString *docPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

   if (!strFile) {
        NSLog(@"Error reading file.");
    }

    [timeStampb release];


      timeStampb = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[strFile componentsSeparatedByString:@"\,"]];
        // this .csv file is seperated with new line character
        // if .csv is seperated by comma use "," instesd of "\n"
    for(NSString *countryname in timeStampb) {
        NSLog(@"%@", timeStampb);

    }


    }


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////Delete csv files
//- (IBAction)delet:(id)sender {
//    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];
//    
//    NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"jorge.csv"];
//    NSError *error = nil;
//    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
//}




- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


# pragma – mark table view DataSource Methods
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.dirList count];

}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";



    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier ];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

        UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:(254.0/255.0) green:(251.0/255.0) blue:(248.0/255.0) alpha:1];
        UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];

        bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(253.0/255.0) green:(0.0/255.0) blue:(237.0/255.0) alpha:1];


        [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
        cell.backgroundColor = color;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [timeStampb objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dirList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(0.0/255.0) green:(0.0/255.0) blue:(0.0/255.0) alpha:1];
    cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:8.0];

    cell.detailTextLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0];
    cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(235.0/255.0) green:(120.0/255.0) blue:(33.0/255.0) alpha:1];



    return cell;


}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{



    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);


        currentcsvfile = [self.dirList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ];;

    csvfilenameSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:currentcsvfile];


    NSArray *paths3 = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
    (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory3 = [paths3 objectAtIndex:0];

    //make a file name to write the data to using the documents directory:
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/currentcsvnamefile.txt",
                          documentsDirectory3];
    //create content - four lines of text
    NSString *content =csvfilenameSave;
    //save content to the documents directory
    [content writeToFile:fileName
              atomically:NO
                encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy error:nil];

    [_dirList addObject:_dirList[indexPath.row]];


    NSLog(@"\n current csv csvfilenameSave % ",csvfilenameSave);



//[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"detailsegue" sender:self];

}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Update the delete button's title based on how many items are selected.
    [_dirList removeObject:_dirList[indexPath.row]];



}


-(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)data:(UITableView *)data editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ( editingStyle== UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.data deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [data setEditing:NO animated:YES];


        NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.dirList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
        NSError *error = nil;
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

        [_dirList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];




    }
}

#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate Methods

//- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
//{
//    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
//}


#pragma mark - Delete Button Action


#pragma mark – TableView delegate

- (void)dealloc {
    [_timeStamp release];

    [self.dirList release];
    self.data.delegate = nil;
    self.data.dataSource = nil;


    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

Comment: show your array list - `self.dirList`. Move this line of the code at the end of the method:  `[_dirList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

Comment: An approach I use with success is to monitor the directory for changes, and display files within the directory - independently of any delete/rename/create operations. So when the file related action occurs, your TableView will be updated once the change has been reflected in the filesystem.

Comment: why are you removing object from array in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: Because i need to deleted the file that match the name showing in the cell.

Comment: you have forgot to add the `-beginUpdates` and `-endUpdates` during updating the table; that is what seems a missing thing after the first glance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what you are doing you are removing the value from array at the top. You have to remove the value from array at the end of this function. As i have done in below code, please check my answer and use this code and then tell me if you face any issue. I Update my answer Please check it again.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ( editingStyle== UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    currentcsvfile = [self.dirList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    csvfilenameSave = [NSString stringWithFormat:currentcsvfile];

    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:csvfilenameSave];
    NSError *error = nil;
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

   [_dirList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.data beginUpdates];

    [self.data deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [self.data endUpdates];

    [data setEditing:NO animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! just try it and i ge this error:
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4),

Comment: @Alivajorg, Now you can try it, i just update it. I appoloize i didn't add it in my answer.

Comment: @Alivajorg, Can you add all the tableview code in the question like n umber of rows in tableview and number of sections if you are using that datasource methods

Comment: sure, i just paste the complete code, thanks for the help.

Comment: tried the code and have the same error. Also the csv files are been created in other view.

Comment: @Alivajorg can you comment this didDeselectRowAtIndexPath method and then try it.

Comment: @Alivajorg, i again update my code now you can try it

Answer (score 0):

Call to method `[self.data deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:];` sends a message to the table view to adjust its presentation and thus tableview throws an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` because `_dirList` count is not equal to tableviews row count.

For details look at this article [Inserting and Deleting Rows and Sections](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH10-SW1)

You can handle this by removing the item corresponding to 
the row from `_dirList` array at first and then sending deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation: to the table view.

Try to replace below lines of code inside `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if ( editingStyle== UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    NSString *docPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString *filePath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[self.dirList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

    [_dirList removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.data deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
}
}
```

Hope it will work!